# Excel: Display blank cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate the search of blank cells in two columns(E and F). My goal is to display the address of these blank cells in one message box. And if there is no blank cell then a message box prompting that there are no blank cells found in two columns. I have tried the code so far but this only works for 5th(E) column and no validation that if there is no blank cell it will prompt a message. I am not sure anymore on how I can proceed to achieve my goal for this.

Below is the code I tried so far:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim MsgStr As String
Dim c As Range


lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 2 To lastrow

If Cells(i, 5) = "" Then

        If MsgStr = "" Then

            MsgStr = Cells(i, 5).Address(False, False)

        Else

            MsgStr = MsgStr & "," & Cells(i, 5).Address(False, False)

        End If
End If

Next i

MsgBox MsgStr & " cells are empty"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel).

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long, rng As Range
    Dim MsgStr As String

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    on error resume next
    set rng = range(cells(2, "E"), cells(lastrow, "F")).specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks)
    on error goto 0

    if not rng is nothing then
        msgbox rng.address(0,0) & " are blank"
    else
        msgbox "no blank cells"
    end if

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above code and it works. However, when there are no blanks, it gives me error "No cells were found". Also in range, do I need to change the column to "F"? Just like this - Set rng = Range(Cells(2, "E"), Cells(lastrow, "F")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks). As I need to look for column "E" and "F" for blank cells.

Comment: See minor edit above and yes, just change E to F in one of the cells.